# Nunit3TestAdapter and TFS Build vNext: Getting a warning: Dependent Assembly nunit.framework not found within VS Test step

Tags: tfs, nunit, tfsbuild

I've been scouring various Nunit articles for the past several days trying to figure out the issue with why my Nunit tests are not running.

I am using TFS 2015 Build vNext engine and the Visual Studio Test step to execute my Nunit test cases. The VS 2015 solution used for generating the Nunit test dlls contains the several .net projects and 2 Nunit test projects.  Nunit3.0 and Nunit3.0 Test Nuget packages are being used to create and execute the tests.  [Here is the nuget configuration and nunit.framework reference in my Visual Studio 2015 solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hgrk.jpg).  The test cases run fine in the Visual Studio IDE and compile without error when the solution is build in vNext.

When the VS Test step executes in Build vNext, I get the following warning:

***Warning: Dependent Assembly nunit.framework of E:\TFSBuild_Directory\14\s\EBS\B_WebEnable\ABC.Data\ABC.Data.Core.Nunit.Tests\obj\UnitTesting\ABC.Data.Core.Nunit.Tests.dll not found. Can be ignored if not a NUnit project.***

The VS Test step is configured:
[VS Test Step Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgnAp.png)

I have confirmed on the build server that the nuget packages are getting restored to the build server and the Nunit.framework.dll appear to be in the expected file path as compared to my local path.

Any ideas as to what could be causing this issue?  Any input is appreciated!

Comment: It's not "TFS vNext". Saying that would incorrectly lead people to believe you're talking about a version of TFS that is still in development, such as the TFS "15" public preview.

Comment: Edit made to TFS Build vNext based on [the following link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tfs-vnext)

Comment: I just realized the you were talking about the TFS-vNext tag that was removed.  I added it back in since it was a supported tag in stackoverflow.  I see Microsoft is now calling it [TF Build](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/news/2016)

Comment: It's **not** called "TFS vNext". That tag is for future versions of TFS, not the build system introduced in TFS 2015.

Comment: Understand - how does one go about cleaning up the description for the tfs-vnext tag?  The description is "TFS Build vNext is Microsoft's newest framework for creating builds in TFS. Is is intended as an easy-to-use replacement for the XAML build system."  This is somewhat misleading based on your description of the tag.

Comment: I misread the tag. It's a bad tag and should be eliminated. The build system isn't called "vnext", and if it's about a future version of TFS, it makes the tag incorrect once that version is given an official version number and is shipped.

Comment: What's type of your project? UWP?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT - this test is for a C# project within a solution that also several other projects including an ASP.NET MVC project.  What I'm trying to test is the Data Access Layer (C# project) before I move on to writing test cases for the other C# projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - after stepping away from the issue and coming back to it with fresh eyes, I found the issue causing the nunit.framework.dll issue.

After going step by step through the build definition, I forgot that I had an MSBuild parameter in the build step that was copying the compiled output to another location /p:OutDir=$(build.stagingDirectory)\ABC.  Once I changed the test step to point to the new location, everything worked fine.  Thanks everyone for the feedback!

Comment: This was the last piece of the puzzle for me! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have restored Nunit and Nunit3TestAdapter from Nuget to have a test on my side, but couldn't reproduce your issue. I'd like to share my steps here for your reference:

1. Restore Nunit and Nunit3TestAdapter from Nuget in VS for the test project (as your first screenshot), and check in the packages.config file.
2. In "Visual Studio Test" task, specify `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\packages` in "Path to Custom Test Adaptors". As if there is a packages folder in the sources directory, it is automatically searched for testadapters (It seems you have a long path, you may need to check it).
3. I use the default VS template:

[image]

No error or warning occurred during this process. You can compare your steps with mine and correct yours. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I tried those steps prior to my post.

Comment: I do have the NuGet installer step prior to the build.  I have confirmed that the Nunit and Nunit3TestAdapter are getting restored by this step in the packages path that matches my path to the custom adapter entry.  Based on the log file, TFS does not have a problem finding the Nunit3TestAdapter dll from the NuGet package since it does not throw an error or exception.  I may be wrong, but I'm getting the sense that test dlls generated by Nunit during the build step cannot find the nunit.framework.dll in the restored Nuget path.

Comment: This may sound like a dumb question, but is the known issues with the .sln file located at folder path beneath the Nunit test project?  I notice your example (and others) have the NuGet packages being restored to $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\packages, which assumes the .sln file is located at $(Build.SourcesDirectory).  The solution file is located at E:\TFSBuild_Directory\14\s\E\BWebEnable\EP\EP.Web\EP.WebSite\EP.WebSite.sln and the packages get restored to E:\TFSBuild_Directory\14\s\E\BWebEnable\EP\EP.Web\EP.WebSite\packages.

Comment: Can you see the nunit.framework.dll in the restored Nuget path? Will you get any error besides this warning?

Comment: Yes I have confirmed that the dll is in the expected path.  Here is a portion of the log from the Build Solution step for compiling the test project.

Comment: Yes I have confirmed.  Here is a snippet from build log - 2016-08-23T21:33:13.8957671Z          C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /platform:AnyCPU /errorreport:prompt /define:TRACE /highentropyva+ /reference:E:\TFSBuild_Directory\14\a\E\BS.Data.Core.dll /reference:E:\TFSBuild_Directory\14\a\E\BS.Data.Core.Entities.dll /reference:E:\TFSBuild_Directory\14\a\E\BS.Interfaces.dll /reference:E:\TFSBuild_Directory\14\s\EB\B_WebEnable\BIN\EntitySpaces.Core.dll /reference:E:\TFSBuild_Directory\14\s\EB\B_WebEnable\BIN\EntitySpaces.Interfaces.dll

Comment: [...]/reference:E:\TFSBuild_Directory\14\s\EB\B_WebEnable\BS.UI\BS.UI.WebSite\packages\NUnit3TestAdapter.3.4.1\lib\Mono.Cecil.dll /reference:E:\TFSBuild_Directory\14\s\EB\B_WebEnable\BS.UI\BS.UI.WebSite\packages\NUnit3TestAdapter.3.4.1\lib\Mono.Cecil.Mdb.dll /reference:E:\TFSBuild_Directory\14\s\EB\B_WebEnable\BS.UI\BS.UI.WebSite\packages\NUnit3TestAdapter.3.4.1\lib\Mono.Cecil.Pdb.dll /reference:E:\TFSBuild_Directory\14\s\EB\B_WebEnable\BS.UI\BS.UI.WebSite\packages\NUnit3TestAdapter.3.4.1\lib\Mono.Cecil.Rocks.dll

Comment: [...] /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll" /reference:E:\TFSBuild_Directory\14\s\EB\B_WebEnable\BS.UI\BS.UI.WebSite\packages\NUnit3TestAdapter.3.4.1\lib\nunit.engine.api.dll /reference:E:\TFSBuild_Directory\14\s\EB\B_WebEnable\BS.UI\BS.UI.WebSite\packages\NUnit3TestAdapter.3.4.1\lib\nunit.engine.dll **/reference:E:\TFSBuild_Directory\14\s\EB\B_WebEnable\BS.UI\BS.UI.WebSite\packages\NUnit.3.4.1\lib\net40\nunit.framework.dll**

Comment: Do you have other projects to test this issue? Does this warning message affect your test result?

Comment: this is my first experience with both new TFS Build and Nunit.  As for the test result, no tests are run because it does not recognize the Nunit framework.